# Swift MacOS SpriteKit rightMouseDragged not working

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, sprite-kit

I have a NSViewController/NSView with a SpriteKit Scene filling the whole view.  Here are the events I need to handle:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
override func rightMouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
override func otherMouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
override func rightMouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
override func otherMouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
```

But they are very inconsistent, and I'm not able to get rightMouseDragged working at all.

```
mouseDown works fine in the SKScene
rightMouseDown works fine in the SKScene
otherMouseDown had to be implemented in the viewController and passed on to the scene
mouseDragged worked fine in the SKScene
rightMouseDragged is not working at all
otherMouseDragged had to be implemented in the viewController and passed on to the scene
```

My main need is to fix rightMouseDragged.  It doesn't receive any dragged events either in the view controller or the scene controller.

Comment: There is something else in your code causing this issue. If you create a new SpriteKit project and override the `rightMouseDragged` method on GameScene works fine.    `override func rightMouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {`
        `print(#function)`
    `}`

Comment: Confirmed that it works with the default project.  Looking at differences in detail now.  Also cool use of #function in print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't understand why, but the rightMouseDragged was being delivered to the SKView.  So here's where I needed to implement my event handlers:

```
mouseDown in the SKScene
rightMouseDown in the SKScene
otherMouseDown in the viewController and passed on to the scene
mouseDragged in the SKScene
rightMouseDragged in the SKView and be passed to the scene
otherMouseDragged in the viewController and passed on to the scene
```